# Collecting Parquet data from HDFS to local file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

Given a Parquet dataset distributed on HDFS (metadata file + may `.parquet` parts), how to correctly merge parts and collect the data onto local file system? `dfs -getmerge ...` doesn't work - it merges metadata with actual parquet files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way involving Apache Spark APIs - which provides a solution, but more efficient method without third-party tools may exist.

```
spark> val parquetData = sqlContext.parquetFile("pathToMultipartParquetHDFS")       
spark> parquet.repartition(1).saveAsParquetFile("pathToSinglePartParquetHDFS")

bash> ../bin/hadoop dfs -get pathToSinglePartParquetHDFS localPath
```

Since Spark 1.4 it's better to use `DataFrame::coalesce(1)` instead of `DataFrame::repartition(1)`

Answer (score 1):

you may use pig

```
A = LOAD '/path/to parquet/files' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader as (x,y,z) ;
STORE A INTO 'xyz path' USING PigStorage('|');
```

You may create Impala table on to it, & then use

```
impala-shell -e "query" -o <output>
```

same way you may use Mapreduce as well

Comment: Thanks. That's legit, but I was looking for something without 3rd party tools like Pig, Spark,...

Answer (score 0):

You may use parquet tools 
 `java -jar parquet-tools.jar merge source/ target/`