# Parquet build with HDFS getmerge recovery

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, backup, parquet

The only post that touch a bit the subject is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108123/collecting-parquet-data-from-hdfs-to-local-file-system) but it does not solve my problem.

Here is the problem we collect parquet to a local backup with:

```
$ hadoop fs -getmerge /dir/on/hdfs /local/dir
```

The error made is that we thought that the parquet multiple files organization is due to HDFS writing but we did not understood it was really the parquet file "normal" organization. So (not very much cleverly) we used getmerge of HDFS to do backup. The problem is that our data have been erased and we are now struggling recovering it.

When analyzing (and reading the [doc](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/)) the parquet we found that all the files are originally made of chunk that contains data+metadata in between magic number 'PAR1' and added to this are given 2 - _metadata and _common_metadata - files of metadata.

By observing that the getmerge process files in order (of the original parquet directory on hdfs), I came up with a script that take the data between 2 'PAR1' and make of it a chunk file. 
The first 2 files built are (_common_metadata, _metadata).

```
filePrefix='part-'
finalFilePrefix='part-r-'

awk 'NR%2==0{ print $0 > "part-"i++ }' RS='PAR1' $1

nbFiles=$(ls -lah | grep 'part-' | wc -l)

for num in $(seq 0 $nbFiles)
        do 
        fileName="$filePrefix$num"
        lastName=""
        if [ "$num" -eq "0" ]; then
                lastName="_common_metadata"
                awk '{print "PAR1" $0 "PAR1"}' $fileName > $lastName
        else    

                if [ "$num" -eq "1" ]; then
                        lastName="_metadata"
                        awk '{print "PAR1" $0 "PAR1"}' $fileName > $lastName
                else    
                        if [ -e $fileName ]; then
                                count=$( printf "%05d" $(($num-2)) )
                                lastName="$finalFilePrefix$count.gz.parquet"
                                awk '{print "PAR1" $0 "PAR1"}' $fileName > $lastName
                        fi      
                fi              
        fi
        echo $lastName
        truncate --size=-1 $lastName
        rm -f "$fileName"
done

mv $1 $1.backup
mkdir $1
mv _* $1
mv part* $1
```

Some observation about the script:

1. It takes a "getmerge" parquet file in parameter
2. All the part created are moved to a directory named after the original file (the later being renamed filename.backup)
3. A byte must be taken at the end of each file - truncate - this is empirically made as the spark sc.load.parquet() could not read metadata files otherwise)
4. Eventually we use hadoop fs -put to upload it to hdfs.
5. Try to load it as a Dataframe
   As I said the _metadata (and _common_metadate files apparently) are read ok but still we have and error when loading the chunks:

The code:

```
val newDataDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/tmp/userActionLog2-leclerc-culturel-2016.09.04.parquet")
newDataDF.take(1)
```

The error:

```
newDataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [bson: binary]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0  (TID 5, hdp-node4.affinytix.com): java.io.IOException: can not read class    org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader: don't know what type: 13
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.read(Util.java:216)
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.readPageHeader(Util.java:65)
at  org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$WorkaroundChunk.readPageHeader(ParquetFileReader.java:668)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:546)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:496)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.java:604)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.loadBatch(UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.java:218)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.java:196)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:194)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1881)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1881)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: parquet.org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: don't know what type: 13
at parquet.org.apache.thrift.protocol.TCompactProtocol.getTType(TCompactProtocol.java:806)
at parquet.org.apache.thrift.protocol.TCompactProtocol.readFieldBegin(TCompactProtocol.java:500)
at org.apache.parquet.format.InterningProtocol.readFieldBegin(InterningProtocol.java:158)
at org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader.read(PageHeader.java:828)
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.read(Util.java:213)
... 32 more
```

Given that our data are at stake here, if somebody had any idea that could help, I warmly thank him(er) in advance.

Bye

Answer (score 2):

I have answered the question.

The basic idea that I had at the beginning is ok. The problem is just that awk (in the solution script) is adding numerous character.
So the parquet chunks are unreadable after that.

The solution is to manipulate the merged file by programming (python, perl...).
Here is the python solution I come up with. It is equivalent to the preceding one with the exception that it does not add useless characters.

The code:

```
print "create parquet script."
import sys 
filename = sys.argv[1]
import locale
currencode=locale.getpreferredencoding()

import io
print "====================================================================="
print "Create parquet from: ", filename
print "defautl buffer size: ", io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
print "default encoding of the system: ", currencode
print "====================================================================="

import re
magicnum = "PAR1"
with io.open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
res = [ magicnum + chunk + magicnum for chunk in filter(lambda s: s!="", re.split(magicnum, content)) ]

szcontent = len(res[2:])
for i in range(0,szcontent) :
        si = str(i)
        write_to_binfile("part-r-{}.gz.parquet".format(si.zfill(5)), res[i+2])

write_to_binfile("_common_metadata", res[0])
write_to_binfile("_metadata", res[1])

import os
os.system("mv {} {}.backup".format(filename, filename))
os.system("mkdir {}".format(filename))
os.system("mv _* {}".format(filename))
os.system("mv part* {}".format(filename))
```

Observation:
The parquet file must not be to much big as the python function load the whole thing in memory as a string (several dozen megabytes are ok)!
Must execute on linux/unix as the system call by the end are unix based.

Bye